# Large scale mailout platform using PHP

Tags: java, php, mysql, email

What is the best practice for sending email campaigns?

My company is asking me to come up with an application that is able to send hundres of thousands of emails per day.

We have the capacity to send this amount using Amazon SES.

As a PHP developer I have created a script with PHP to find for example 100,000 records from the database and send emails one by one according to use preferences. This script is executed using cron several times a day.

But this approach fails due to the script being slow, and the browser time outs (Even with high php `set_timeout`). Or in other words, its not robust and reliable.

I was thinking to perhaps use Java or some other "active" programming language that is alive in the background and is able to handle this without timing out etc.

Has any one of you had this issue before? What is your suggestions for this large scale mailout platform?

Side note 1: We call an API in order to send emails, no sendmail etc.
Side note 2: It has to be able to Call an API around 40 times per second, my script only calls 1 per second
Side note 3: Database is MySQL

Comment: If the email messages do not need to be customized (i.e. many people get the same message), you can batch send emails using BCC.

Comment: Thats the thing. Emails need to be customized for each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do long running tasks in PHP I recommend running the script from the command line, without a web server. You won't have the timeout issue.

Comment: Combine that with a logical categorization of addresses to different scripts, perhaps, and you're in business.

Answer (score 1):

WOW - Sounds like a SPAM factory :) Anyways, I would look into writing some type of service that can spin multiple threads up and process the requests that way. 40 times per second to the cloud seems like a lot. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Better purchase something like expressmail from godaddy . 
Always having the chance to mark as spam if we do manually using php